# Debian packaging - Why MD5sums changed?

Tags: debian, packaging, md5sum, software-packaging

I have an application consisting in two differents war plus some conf files that i'm packaging in a debian package.

When i'm typing "md5sum warname.war" in a console i have a md5sum hash that is different than the md5 of the same file in the "ms5sums" file in the control.tar.gz archive in my debian packaging.

If in install the package on a test machine, the md5 of the installed war are the same as the one in the md5sums control file.

Why is the debian packaging process changing my md5 sums (and i assume my wars) ? I suspect a kind of compression here but is there a way to keep the sames md5 before and after packaging ?

**md5 sums from the console :**

> 3d1f0c150a65b801b7d4de3a5ff34058  war1.war
>
> b718fd50c445df197312eb8b24c7048b  war2.war

**Content of my .deb/control.tar.gz/md5sums**

> e8b78560d7f1623ffe4a363686243200  var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/war1.war
>
> 3ee74b989774fe2b624f33951843c605  var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/war2.war

I need consistancy in these because this break traceability of my wars from my automatic builds output to my deployment test machines.

I build my package using the "debuild -us -uc" command within a standard debian folder structure (debian/config debian/control debian/install, etc...)